# Scan dates in a dataframe and create a new one with column names based on the year of those dates

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 
1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 
1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 
1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 
1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 
1651363200, 1654041600, 1656633600, 1659312000, 1661990400, 1664582400, 
1667260800, 1669852800, 1672531200, NA), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Actual-retail and recreation` = c(5.26666666666667, 
-15.5806451612903, -41.4333333333333, -27.1290322580645, -15.7666666666667, 
-14.8709677419355, -14.9677419354839, -14.9333333333333, -15.7741935483871, 
-19.8666666666667, -19.741935483871, -25.5806451612903, -23.4285714285714, 
-10.8387096774194, -8.3, -5.41935483870968, -3.53333333333333, 
-3.87096774193548, -4.67741935483871, -6.1, -5.54838709677419, 
-7.43333333333333, -6.7741935483871, -18.9677419354839, -12.3571428571429, 
-10.4193548387097, -8.66666666666667, -6.06451612903226, -6.83333333333333, 
-8.64516129032258, -7.09677419354839, -8.73333333333333, -8.53333333333333, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like:

[image]

and I want to reorganize in a way that we will have as column names the `"Year"` and all the years found in the data and as values in the rows the months found in the data and their correspondent values like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could reshape to wide with `pivot_wider` after creating the `month` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   transmute(Year = year(Date), month = format(Date, "%b"), 
     `Actual-retail and recreation`) %>% 
   drop_na() %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Year,
     values_from = `Actual-retail and recreation`) %>%
   arrange(match(month, month.abb))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   month `2020` `2021` `2022`
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Jan    NA    -25.6  -19.0 
 2 Feb     5.27 -23.4  -12.4 
 3 Mar   -15.6  -10.8  -10.4 
 4 Apr   -41.4   -8.3   -8.67
 5 May   -27.1   -5.42  -6.06
 6 Jun   -15.8   -3.53  -6.83
 7 Jul   -14.9   -3.87  -8.65
 8 Aug   -15.0   -4.68  -7.10
 9 Sep   -14.9   -6.1   -8.73
10 Oct   -15.8   -5.55  -8.53
11 Nov   -19.9   -7.43  NA   
12 Dec   -19.7   -6.77  NA
```